# Parsing different complex locale string to number

Tags: express, parsing, number-formatting

On my express.ts backend I receive input data from a csv/xlsx converted to json. I have no control over the formatting of this data, as it is updated by the customer who often changes number formats on the columns.

So I have data that represents a numeric entity but which can arrive both in the form of a number and a string and I need to manage all possible parsing cases.

Here are some examples (counting that the data may contain thousands separators and that the separator is represented by a ".", meanwhile decimal separators can be represented both by "." or ",").

If I receive **"1200"**, **"1.200"** (strings), or **1200** (number) as input, the parsed data will be **1200** for all three cases.

If I receive **"1.200,25"**, **"1200.25"**, **"1200,25"** (strings) or **1200.25** (number) as input, the parsed result will be, for all four cases, **1200.25**.

At the moment I managed to handle more or less all the parsing cases, but I have a problem to handle the cases where there may be thousands separators, because the replace technique I'm using conflicts with the decimal separators.

Is there an algorithm or library that makes it easier to deal with all these cases, remembering that I can't know in advance the type of formatting of the data? Thanks